# Read data from separate CSV file in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, database, spreadsheet, csv

I have a very large CSV file (many thousands of rows) that I want to work with. Due to the size of the file, I don't want to import it into openoffice. Rather, I want to create a spreadsheet that contains formulas & graphs that read from this (or any other) CSV file I point it it.

Ideally the spreadsheet will ask me what CSV file I want to use, allowing me to change the data source dynamically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The way I see your problem.... I only see one solution (and that's probably not the on you were hoping for :) )

I think the only way is for you to open the csv in BASIC (macro programming language from OOO), I wish I could help you more but I only program in VBA (excel) or Python.

If this was my problem, I would implement what I needed in python (reading and calculation) then have python make and intermediate CSV file and use BASIC to open that one (after basic had called the python script).